# FileZilla preview files which will be uploaded

Tags: file-upload, ftp, filezilla

I am using the "Overwrite if different size or source newer" option in FileZilla when I am uploading files, which is a great feature. But I need one more step before I push files which would be to scan the whole upload section and show me what files are different sizes or sources newer then I would confirm the exact changes.

Is it possible with FileZilla or would I use another software to do that?

Comment: I believe this should be the default behavior of FileZilla already, unless you have "Always use this action" checked.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as I click OK it starts uploading files which are different. I want FileZilla to scan first and show me what to upload and I will confirm.

Comment: You mean a diff list of files?

Comment: Yes, I need list of files which FileZilla found as different then I would confirm, lets assume I have 1K files in total, and filezilla would scan entire ftp section (which is already doing) and show me files to be uploaded (lets assume 15 files). Right now it uploads right away while it is scanning.

Comment: Hello from 2022. You may use [Filezilla PRO](https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/search/preview) or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full). They both have synchronize and preview option.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View > Directory Comparison > Click "Hide Identical Files".  Then, you can toggle Directory Comparison with CTRL+O.  I also recommend using the hotkey to toggle Synchronized Browsing (CTRL+Y).

You can choose Compare Filesize or Compare modification time.  In my mind, if you're going to rely on the mod time, I would also set it to "Preserve timestamps of transferred files" under the "Transfer Menu" (CTRL+U to toggle).  I think that makes more logical sense than having to worry about uploading your file within a minute to keep them "identical".  You can also have a threshold of time set for this value. Go to Edit > Settings > Interface > File Lists.  Under "Directory Comparison" on that screen you can increase the Comparison Threshold.

Is that what you're looking for?

[image: View > Directory Comparison > Hide Identical Files]

Comment: not exactly, I do not want to compare files directory to directory basis. As I mentioned above, lets assume I have a web project and I want to deploy everything at once. When I select entire root folders, filezilla starts from first folder, compares files and upload them if different or newer. I instead of uploading them right away I want filezilla to add them into a preview list. Then I can see what files it will upload and I will confirm. Shortly; I will go root folder select all folders and right click, I expect a context menu like "Add files to queue if different or newer than destination"